# Replace decimals within a special character in file

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to read in file and replace all the decimals that are only between the thorn character in it such that:
ie.

```
þ219.91þ
þ122.1919þ
þ467.426þ
þ104.351þ
þ104.0443þ
```

will become

```
þ219þ
þ122þ
þ467þ
þ104þ
þ104þ
```

The gist of something I'm trying to replicate that works in Notepad++ (regex replacing - below) and trying to replicate it in python (code below which is not working). Any suggestions?

In Notepad++:

```
Find: (\xFE\d+)\.\d+(\xFE)
Replace: $1$2
```

Python:

```
for line in file:
        line = re.sub("(\xFE\d+)\.\d+(\xFE)", "\xFE\d+\xFE", line)
```

Comment: The replacement string in Python would just be `r"\1\2"`.  Your attempt failed because it contains no references to the matched groups, you're replacing with a literal string.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! this seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would be necessary to have \xFE and this might simply work:

```
import re

regex = r"(þ\d+)\.\d+(þ)"

test_str = ("þ219.91þ\n"
    "þ122.1919þ\n"
    "þ467.426þ\n"
    "þ104.351þ\n"
    "þ104.0443þ")

subst = "\\1\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not replacing decimals: you're truncating the values.  Will the mathematical treatment do for you?  This assumes that all lines are of the format you show.

```
for line in file:
    _, val, _ = line.split('þ')   # null string, value, null string
    line = 'þ' + str(int(val))+ 'þ'
```

Note that you *could* reduce this a little with a single line in the loop:

```
    line = 'þ' + str(int(line.split('þ')[1]))+ 'þ'
```

Comment: I am running into this error: 
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file, but no encoding declared. 

Is there a way to declare 'þ' encoding properly (sorry not really familiar with it)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a one-liner such as:

```
f = ["þ219.91þ", "þ122.1919þ", "þ467.426þ", "þ104.351þ", "þ104.0443þ"]

print(["þ{}þ".format(int(float(l.strip("þ")))) for l in f])
```

**Result**:

```
['þ219þ', 'þ122þ', 'þ467þ', 'þ104þ', 'þ104þ']
```